# Netbeans errors "No library found for the namespace" when using xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"

Tags: jsf, netbeans, xml-namespaces, jsf-2.2

In net beans, JSF Application i can't able to include xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" in .xhtml file, instead of xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html". Its showing "No library found for the namespace". What should i need to do to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: Upgrade to Mojarra 2.2.2 and retry. 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 had several troubles with new namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, i was using netbeans 6.9 version, so i uninstalled that and installed 7.3.1. It works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to configure the new schema location of the namespace you're using in `faces-config.xml`?

Check out [this](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/) post.